# Does autolayout add width constraints that I can't remove?

Tags: ios, autolayout, storyboard, interface-builder, nslayoutconstraint

Whenever I write for iOS, I always struggle with Autolayout. Does anyone else have these problems? How do you overcome it? Have you reverted to alternatives like SnapKit?

This is what I'm trying to accomplish:

```
            UITableViewCell  
+-------------------------------------+
| +-------------------------+ +-----+ |
| | Label #1                | | #2  | |
| +-------------------------+ +-----+ |
+-------------------------------------+
```

I want the following:

- Label #1 to be vertically centered
- Label #2 to be vertically centered
- The leading space from the left bounds to Label #1 to be constant
- The trailing space from Label #2 to the right bounds to be constant
- The horizontal spacing between Label #1 and Label #2 to be constant

These are the warnings I'm getting: Ambiguous Layout Group

- Main.storyboard: warning: Ambiguous Layout: Vertical position is ambiguous for "Label #2". (1)
- Main.storyboard 2 views are horizontally ambiguous.
- Main.storyboard Width is ambiguous for "Label #1". (2)
- Main.storyboard Width and horizontal position are ambiguous for "Label #2". (2)
  Main.storyboard: warning: Ambiguous Layout: Vertical position is ambiguous for "Label #1". (1)

My thoughts:

1. Vertical position should not be ambiguous. If I don't set it to be vertically centered, it appears wrong on my device.
2. No width constraint has been set by me. I don't even see any width constraints in IB to remove.

Comment: Can you create a debug repo and give me the link? Seem like it's easier and faster for solving your problem.

Comment: Thanks @trungduc. Figured it out though. The warnings weren't very good, because "ambiguous" sounds like I have something I don't need. It turns out I needed something I didn't have: one of the labels to have a constant width set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only use autolayout libraries if you want to add constraints programmatically, such as `SnapKit` indeed.

One thing to remember by someone who's new in iOS, a view should have `Width`, `Height`, `X`, and `Y`.

Now, doing what you want using the interface builder is pretty much easy. When you do your layout in Storyboard or Xib, there should be a warning or error if you're doing your layout not properly.

YOU want the following, see if it is implemented:

- Label #1 to be vertically centered to the superView (cell) ✅
- Label #2 to be vertically centered to the superView (cell) ✅
- The leading space from the left bounds to Label #1 to be constant ✅
- The trailing space from Label #2 to the right bounds to be constant ✅
- The horizontal spacing between Label #1 and Label #2 to be constant ✅

As you can see in my constraints, there are 5.

1. Leading distance from the superView to the leading of label 1.
2. Center Y to the cell of label 1.
3. Center Y to the cell of label 2.
4. Trailing distance from the superView to the trailing of label 2.
5. Distance of label 1 to the label 2

Lastly, without this #6, you should get an error or warning.

6. One of the two views (labels) should have a constant width, I'm putting the constant width to the label 2 as per your requirements.

As for your question:

> Does autolayout add width constraints that I can't remove?

No, unless you add it automatically by fixing the warnings/errors in your interface builder.

Hope it helps.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Glenn! It worked! The problem is that I didn't set a constant width on either of the labels.

Comment: That's okay, cause `UILabel` does not need a constant width and constant height constraints as far as I know, based on my experience. Try to use `UIView`s instead of `UILabel` and see that you need to set a constant width. :D